# MonoTouch 4.0 linker failing

Tags: xamarin.ios

I just upgraded to MonoTouch 4.0 and I'm getting this error when the Linker behavior is set to "Link SDK assmeblies only". Anyone got a fix for this?

```
Error 1: mtouch failed with the following message:

Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
at MTouch.LinkAssemblies (System.String main, System.Collections.Generic.List`1& assemblies) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at MTouch.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0   (1)
```

Comment: Please file a bug with a sample at http://monotouch.net/Support

Comment: Thanks for the offer Geoff. See answer below. Would you mind commenting on why this solves the issue?

Comment: It probably is referencing a type that moved in the BCL, if you could file it we could figure out why and fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what the issue was. I'm using bindings for a third party obj-c lib and for some reason the outputted .dll from running btouch from way back when doesn't work with MonoTouch 4.0. I had to run btouch again to get a new binding .dll. Works like a charm now.